# GNU Make forgets prerequisites?

Tags: gnu-make

This is a bit complex so I have uploaded an example [here](http://misc.janssons.org/make_problem.tgz).

How to test it:

- Download the tarball and unpack it
- cd make_problem/make
- make aclean (forgot to remove the archive from the archive ;))
- make alib (will re-create the simple and silly archive you just removed)
- ./weird.sh

What weird.sh does is simply to touch a source file, re-make, touch another source file, re-make, a few times.

This is what the output looks like on my Linux system using GNU Make 3.81:

```
$ ./weird.sh
####  1  ####
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wextra  -o ../swu/1/src/foo1.o ../swu/1/src/foo1.c

ar cr ../make/libmine.a ../swu/1/src/foo1.o
====  1  ====
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wextra  -o ../swu/1/src/bar1.o ../swu/1/src/bar1.c

ar cr ../make/libmine.a ../swu/1/src/bar1.o
####  2  ####
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wextra  -o ../swu/1/src/foo2.o ../swu/1/src/foo2.c

====  2  ====
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wextra  -o ../swu/1/src/bar2.o ../swu/1/src/bar2.c

####  3  ####
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wextra  -o ../swu/1/src/foo3.o ../swu/1/src/foo3.c

====  3  ====
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wextra  -o ../swu/1/src/bar3.o ../swu/1/src/bar3.c

####  4  ####
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wextra  -o ../swu/1/src/foo4.o ../swu/1/src/foo4.c

====  4  ====
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wextra  -o ../swu/1/src/bar4.o ../swu/1/src/bar4.c

####  5  ####
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wextra  -o ../swu/1/src/foo5.o ../swu/1/src/foo5.c

====  5  ====
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wextra  -o ../swu/1/src/bar5.o ../swu/1/src/bar5.c

####  6  ####
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wextra  -o ../swu/1/src/foo6.o ../swu/1/src/foo6.c

====  6  ====
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wextra  -o ../swu/1/src/bar6.o ../swu/1/src/bar6.c

####  7  ####
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wextra  -o ../swu/1/src/foo7.o ../swu/1/src/foo7.c

====  7  ====
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wextra  -o ../swu/1/src/bar7.o ../swu/1/src/bar7.c

ar cr ../make/libmine.a ../swu/1/src/bar7.o
####  8  ####
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wextra  -o ../swu/1/src/foo8.o ../swu/1/src/foo8.c

====  8  ====
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wextra  -o ../swu/1/src/bar8.o ../swu/1/src/bar8.c

$
```

Now I expected the archive be re-built every time a source was touched, but that evidently did not happen.

Can anyone explain this?
And explain how to make sure it always works as expected?

Comment: With Solaris 10 and GNU Make 3.80, it actually seems to work as expected.
Under Linux, with GNU Make 3.80, I get the same behavior as seen above.
Does anyone know of platform-dependent problems with GNU Make?

Comment: Sorry, the uploaded example was cluttered with crap. It's now replaced with a cleaner version (and doesn't require the initial "make aclean")

Comment: I'd upvote the question if the problem was reduced to a small makefile fragment included in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the relatively low resolution of file modification timestamps, which causes make to get confused when you run it twice in a row really quickly, like your `weird.sh` does.

Specifically, `weird.sh` will:

1. touch `foo1.c`
2. run make, which

   1. rebuilds `foo1.o` and
   2. rebuilds `libmine.a`
3. touch `bar1.c`
4. run make, which

   1. rebuilds `bar1.o`
   2. maybe(see below) rebuilds `libmine.a`

If the time between step 2.2 and step 4.2 is less than the timestamp resolution of your filesystem, then make sees `libmine.a` as already having the *same* timestamp as `bar1.o`, and so doesn't rebuild it.

The timestamp resolution for the Linux ext3 file system is 1 second. This [explanation from the maintainer of make](http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-make@gnu.org/msg02239.html) describes the problem in more detail, and also mentions that Solaris has better timestamp resolution, which probably explains why your example works as expected there.

If this is a problem for you in a real application, you might try the ext4 filesystem, which has nanosecond resolution timestamps. Otherwise, just put a `sleep 1` after each make command in `weird.sh`, and the problem goes away :-)

Comment: Thanks, this makes me kinda curious about how the hi-res timestamps are read, as they can't be in a normal stat struct. But that's a side track.

I would have given a short example in the question itself if I could, but as there was pretty much text, I figured this would be nicer. Sorry if I figured wrong.

Comment: Extra fields were added to the stat struct to hold the nanosecond part of each timestamp.